# TShark Cli question

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am looking over a CTF writeup and I have a problem in reproducing a single command:

```
tshark -r challenge.pcapng usb.bDescriptorType and usb.urb_type==67 -T fields -e usb.bus_id -e usb.device_address -e usb.idVendor -e usb.idProduct
```

Is it correct, or how should I use the `-T` parameter?

Comment: What do you want to outcome to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct?

No.

`usb.bDescriptorType and usb.urb_type==67` is a display/read filter, so you have to use a `-Y` flag with it, and put it in quotes:

```
tshark -r challenge.pcapng -Y "usb.bDescriptorType and usb.urb_type==67" -T fields -e usb.bus_id -e usb.device_address -e usb.idVendor -e usb.idProduct
```